# Make environment variables accessible to Gradle task

Tags: bash, gradle, kotlin, ros, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I need to run a Gradle task inside a shell environment, which must be created before the task is launched. Using `commandLine` or `executable` is not appropriate, as I need to run the task in the same process as the shell script. Originally, I called the script directly inside `gradlew`, but later I decided to source it from `build.gradle.kts` and call subsequent tasks through `gradlew`:

```
val setupRosEnv by tasks.creating(Exec::class) {
    executable = "bash"

    args("-c", "source $rosPath/setup.sh && source gradlew myTask")
}
```

I can build everything by running `./gradlew setupRosEnv` from the CLI. Besides sourcing the script then running `gradlew`, is there a way to achieve this using the Gradle API? The current solution seems a bit hacky, and is clunky for other tasks to depend on `setupRosEnv`, as this will lead to an infinite loop or must be explicitly handled to prevent tasks being run more than once.

As the shell script itself is generated by ROS, it cannot be translated to Gradle or easily parsed.

Answer (score 5):

It depends how your gradle task `myTask` use the environment. If it use the environment by `System.getenv`, you can do use the following step.

1. parse the bash environment file `env.sh` and load all variables into `Properties`
2. append the environment variables to current process in `java.lang.ProcessEnvironment` by reflection
3. use the injected environment variables in your build task

Below is just roughly an example code copied from Java with minor modification, but it works fine in gradle build task.

```
task myEnvironInjected << {
    println("task with injected enviroment")
}

task myBuildTask(dependsOn: myEnvironInjected) << {
    def v1 = System.getenv("V1")
    println("my build task running V1=${v1}")
}

myEnvironInjected.doFirst {
    final Map<String, String> bashEnvMap = new HashMap<>();

    try {
        // a simple simulation of bash command source env.sh
        // use it carefully
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream
                ("/path/to/env.sh")));

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.length() > 0 && line.startsWith("export ")) {
                String newLine = line.trim().replaceFirst("^export ", "");
                // remove single or double quote from the value if it has
                int quoteIndex = newLine.indexOf('=')+1;
                if (quoteIndex < newLine.length() && (newLine.charAt(quoteIndex) == ('"' as char) ||
                        newLine.charAt(quoteIndex) == ('\'' as char))) {
                    newLine = newLine.substring(0, quoteIndex) + newLine.substring(quoteIndex+1, newLine.length()-1);
                }
                writer.write(newLine);
                writer.newLine();
            }
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);

        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
            bashEnvMap.put(((String) entry.getKey()), ((String) entry.getValue()));
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (Class<?> aClass : Collections.class.getDeclaredClasses()) {
        if ("java.util.Collections\$UnmodifiableMap".equals(aClass.getName())) {
            try {
                Field mapField = aClass.getDeclaredField("m");
                mapField.setAccessible(true);
                Object mapObject = mapField.get(System.getenv());
                Map<String, String> environMap = ((Map<String, String>) mapObject);
                environMap.putAll(bashEnvMap);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> envEntry : System.getenv().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(envEntry.getKey() + "=" + envEntry.getValue());
    }
}
```

My test file `env.sh` looks like this.

```
export V1="v1 vvv"
export V2='v 2222'
export V3=v33333
```

If your build task use the environment variables not by `System.getenv`, your hacking method might be the best solution.

```
task myBuildTaskWithSourceEnv(type: Exec) {
    commandLine '/bin/bash'
    setArgs(['-c', 'source ../env.sh;set;../gradlew :app:assembleDebug'])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. If I understand correctly, you’re saying I should parse the contents of the bash script? This seems really messy and prone to failure. Is this a common thing to do in Gradle? I would think there should be a better way to do this...

Comment: Also, the bash script does not contain the export statements directly, but rather calls a bunch of external things to configure the environment. So I do not think your solution will work.